# Why does GNU expr produce 0 for "expr a \> -aa"?

Tags: gnu-coreutils, expr

Does any one know why

```
$ expr a \> -a
```

produce 1 and

```
$ expr a \> -aa
```

produce 0?

The version of coreutils:

```
$ pacman -Q coreutils                 
coreutils 9.4-2
```

It produce the same result when replace the `-` to `+` or `*`:

```
$ expr a \> +a
1
$ expr a \> +aa
0
$ expr a \> \*a
1
$ expr a \> \*aa
0
```

Why not treat the operator as an ordinary character?

**Update:** This is related to UTF-8 sorting:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C expr a \> -a
1
$ LC_COLLATE=C expr a \> -aa
1
```

Comment: **What locale?** Many ignore punctuation (and usually casing and accents also) on the first pass of comparison, and use them only to break ties., to give the same collation traditionally used for dictionaries, indexes, library shelving, etc. Check also what your `sort` does with those values as input lines, or `ls` with filenames.

Comment: Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/why-does-ls-sorting-ignore-non-alphanumeric-characters and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/sort-produces-output-in-a-weird-order